# Как указать ограничение xml schema unique для елементов разного уровня

Tags: xml

Как указать ограничение xml schema unique для элементов разного уровня.
Например елементы `ID` и `ItemA` в xml-файле:

```
<root>
 <ID>1</ID>
 <Items>
  <Item>
   <ItemA>1</ItemA>
   <ItemB>2</ItemB>
   <ItemC>3</ItemC>
  </Item>
  <Item>
   <ItemA>4</ItemA>
   <ItemB>5</ItemB>
   <ItemC>6</ItemC>
  </Item>
  <Item>
   <ItemA>7</ItemA>
   <ItemB>8</ItemB>
   <ItemC>9</ItemC>
  </Item>
 </Items>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для приведённого xml можно использовать, например, такую схему:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element name="Items">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Item">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ItemA" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                    <xs:element name="ItemB" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                    <xs:element name="ItemC" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:unique name="global_unique">
      <xs:selector xpath="ID | Items/Item/*"/>
      <xs:field xpath="."/>
    </xs:unique>

  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XPath ко всем элементам, которые должны быть уникальными, указывается в узле `selector` с помощью оператора объединения `|`.

Comment: Благодарю за Ваш ответ.

Comment: @prunum, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).